# When exactly has an exception been caught?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, terminate

I get this *terminating with uncaught exception* even though I thought I had caught the exception. Here is some example code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

void throwing(int x)
{
  if(x) throw std::runtime_error("x non-null");
}

int main()
{
  try {
    throwing(1);
  } catch(std::runtime_error const&ex) {
    std::clog << "error: \"" << ex.what() << '\"' << std::endl;
    std::terminate();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

which produces (after reporting *error: "x non-null"*) the said message (using clang++ with `std=c++11`). So, when *exactly* has the exception been caught and hence deemed *uncaught* in the sense of `terminate()` not reporting it (again)? Or, equivalently (or not?): how can I catch an exception, report its `what()`, and `terminate()` without getting this blurb?

(I could refrain from reporting the `what()` and just `terminate()`, but I want to report the `what()` in my own way.)

Comment: You should read a bit about `terminate`. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abort/

Comment: I *think* it's because you still have an active exception within the `catch` block. One way to fix your problem is to call [`std::abort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort) directly instead of `std::terminate()`.

Comment: @Praetorian So does *uncaught* mean *active*? Why then does it report an *uncaught* exception (rather than an *active* one)?

Comment: Well, an uncaught exception is by definition *active*, until your program terminates. I don't see any mention of *uncaught exception* in either [gcc or clang output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c107487c0f68d855)

Comment: @Praetorian **1** the question is not whether an *uncaught exception is active*, but whether an *active exception is uncaught*. **2** I get *terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error* with clang (v3.3, OS/X 10.9) and *terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'* with gcc (4v.9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since noone provided an answer to this, and it seems like my comment was either not clear enough or overlooked, I'll post a full answer:

> Or, equivalently (or not?): how can I catch an exception, report its what(), and terminate() without getting this blurb?

If you read carefully thru [the reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/terminate/?kw=terminate), you'll notice `std::terminate()` by default calls `abort()`, which causes the program to terminate returning a platform-dependent *unsuccessful termination* error code to the host environment.

Now, answering the quoted question: either use `exit(int status)` (which is a [better solution](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/), since you handled the exception) instead of `terminate`, or **[change](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/set_terminate/)** the **terminate handler**.